# -ObjC flag for Restkit causes compilation error when I add libZSDK_API.a

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, zebra-printers

I am using the RestKit to consume web services. RestKit worked fine until I tried add the libZSDK_API.a library (this library is to manage the zebra printers by Network or bluetooth)

Several Tutorials indicate this step to add the RestKit to iOS Project:

- Add in "other linker flags" the value -ObjC

But this flag (-ObjC) cause compilation error when I added the library, When I remove this flag the iOS app compile correctly but when I execute the app is crashed because the Project does not have the -ObjC flag.

I'm getting this Compilation error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Linea", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libZSDK_API.a(LineaBtPrinterConnection.o)
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_LineaBtPrinterConnection)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Zebra API links to another API for Bluetooth communication thru the IPC Linea Sled device. The `LineaBtPrinterConnection` links to that library file (`libdtdev.a`).  Normally, if you don't care about the BT communication thru the sled, you don't have to link that library in, but since you're adding that `-ObjC` flag, it's loading that file and looking for that library.

If you add the `libdtdev.a` library to your project, that error should go away.  The library should be included in the download you got from Zebra under the "Demos" project folder.  If you need to actually use the sled, depending on the firmware version of the sled, you may need a new version from IPC, which you can get if you [sign up as a developer on their site.](http://www.ipcprint.com/)

Comment: Yes, the last week I solved my problem when I included the libdtdev.a to project and all works fine!!  thanks very much

Comment: Does anyone know where I can get a version of libdtdev.a that was built more recently to include arm64?

Comment: Thank for the quick response Ovi, I've registered to their developer portal but it is pending approval. Is that the only source?

Comment: Yeah, if you want to support the Linea iPhone sleds, you need to be a registered developer with them and get your app approved by them before going to the play store, etc.  Do you actually want to support the sleds? If not, you can just remove all calls to Zebra's LineaBtPrinterConnection in your code and then it shouldn't try to link that lib

Comment: Yep that's the problem. I'm not even supporting sleds or anything Linea I am just printing to a Zebra mobile printer. Trouble is I need -ObjC in linker flags so the ZebraSDK needs the libdtdev.a library even though I'm not using it. Annoyingly every version of the library I have found is not built for arm64.

Comment: Regardless, Linea have now accepted my registration so I've downloaded a newer library from there. Thanks for your help Ovi.

Answer (score 1):

I bet your app would build successfully for the device.  The problem you're seeing is when you build for the simulator (which I can tell because it says "`not found for architecture i386`").

How are you building "`libZSDK_API`"?  From source?  If so, make sure you also build it for the simulator.  If not, the vendor needs to include symbols for "`i386`" in the .a file they deliver.

Comment: The project does not build for the device, I can't understand one thing, The project compile correctly when I remove the -ObjC, but the RestKit cause crash when the project does not have -ObjC flag...