# Disable -ObjC for one Framework in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker

I am currently using some Frameworks which use the -ObjC Other Linker Flag. (RestKit)

Now I have to implement another Framework which does not work with the -ObjC Flag set.

Is there a way do Disable this Flag for this particular Framework, or to enable it only for RestKit?

Comment: You probably checked this out but is this similiar with your question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797711/objc-flag-for-restkit-causes-compilation-error-when-i-add-libzsdk-api-a

Comment: Similiar, but not helpful. I have found a Solution and will post it soon, after some tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used

```
-force_load $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libRestKit.a
```

in Other Linker Flags and removed -ObjC and -all_load

Works fine.